# ffmpeg in python script

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing

I would like to run the following command in a python script, I also want to make it loop over several videos in a folder. This is the command I want to run.

`ffmpeg -i mymovie.avi -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 output%d.png`

I want to fit it in something like this:

```
import ffmpy
import os

path = './Videos/MyVideos/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    name = filename.replace('.avi','')
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path,name))
    *ffmpeg command here*
```

I found a wrapper for ffmpeg called ffmpy, could this be a solution?

Comment: And have you given any thought as to how you will do any of this that you can share?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[From a brief look at FFMPY, you could do this using ffmpy.FFmpeg, as that allows any and all FFMPEG command line options, including -f.](http://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest) -- Click the link for documentation.

You could do the FFMPEG command with `os.system`. You'll need to import OS anyway to iterate through the files.

You would need to iterate through all the files in a directory though. This would be the more challenging bit, it's quite easy with a for loop though.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if (filename.endswith(".mp4")): #or .avi, .mpeg, whatever.
        os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 output%d.png".format(filename))
    else:
        continue
```

The above code iterates through the directory at `path`, and uses command prompt to execute your given FFMPEG command, using the filename (if it's a video file) in place of `mymovie.avi`

Comment: The if line should have a ")" at the end, like:
if (filename.endswith(".mp4")):

Answer (score 5):

Dont have reputation to comment, hence adding another response.

Another version of ocelot's answer with the more readable f-string syntax of python -

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if (filename.endswith(".mp4")): #or .avi, .mpeg, whatever.
        os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {filename} -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 output%d.png')
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Try pydemux in https://github.com/Tee0125/pydemux. Pydemux module can extract video frames as in Pillow Image format

```
from PyDemux import Video

v = Video.open('video.mov')

i = 0
while True:
    im = v.get_frame()

    if im is None:
        break

    im.save('output%d.png'%i)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: What if I need to do something else while this main loop is going on? Whatever I am recording shall not be put on pause, so I'd have to have more than one thread or something. Sounds complicated but likely doable. How though?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to use ffmpeg in a python script, e.g. for extracting the last 10 seconds of every video:

`ffmpeg -sseof -10 -i input.mp4 output.mp4`

To apply this to a whole folder of mp4 files:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
suffix = ".mp4"
input_path= Path.home() / "Desktop/foo"
file_paths= [subp for subp in input_path.rglob('*') if  suffix == subp.suffix]
file_paths.sort()

output_path =  Path.home() / "Desktop/foo/new"
output_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for file_p in file_paths:
    input = str(file_p)
    output = str(  output_path / file_p.name  ) 
    command = f"ffmpeg -sseof -10 -i {input} {output}"
    print(command)
    os.system(command)
```